# Android Google Maps animateCamera cause app crash

Tags: android, google-maps

```
UnknownException: (Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {}: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.c
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:612)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(7)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzg.animateCamera(8)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.animateCamera(6)
```

When fit all marker on map, use animateCamera method, I got above error. I have no idea about this error. Can someone give some ideas?

Comment: Post the code plz in which you are getting error

Comment: The error is from flurry, the code has been confused. But I guess the error occurs when call mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundsBuilder.build(), 500)).

Comment: please post full logcat and gradle file as well

Comment: and your code for map fragment or activity